# How to add more containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers, multiple-columns, rows

I have been struggling to add more independent rows that have columns and have their own container. I have managed to build the first container which containers horizontal scrollable avatars
[image]

[image]

Comment: could share design images?

Comment: Please provide your code as a code block and not as an image.